# ffmpeg crop videos and combine them

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I need to combine 2 videos vertically or horizontally. But before this i need to crop one or two of the videos.

Both video sizes need to be 720x640. I need to combine 2 video that has 720x1280 resolution. I first crop them to 720x640 (crop 320px from top and 320px from bottom), then combine vertically.

I can combine same size videos with the command:

> ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -i 2.mp4 -filter_complex
>   "[0:v]scale=520:-1[v0];[1:v]scale=520:-1[v1];[v0][v1]vstack" -c:v
>   libx264 -crf 23 -preset veryfast output.mp4

This command is working but i need a crop operation for this command.

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -i 2.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]crop=iw:640[v0];[1:v]crop=iw:ih/2[v1];[v0][v1]vstack" -c:v libx264 -crf 23 -preset veryfast output.mp4
```

This example shows two methods using crop to get 720x640 from 720x1280. Refer to the [crop filter documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#crop) for more info.